# What is trial login and password?

Tags: login

I am trying Ubuntu for the first time and can’t grt past login and password .   I tried blanks and Ubuntu in different combinations but no luck.  Would like to give it a try but can’t get started. Using LTS version.

Comment: Please explain exactly where you downloaded Ubuntu from, exactly what kind or flavor or version of Ubuntu that you downloaded, and exactly what you did with the download (install? copy? something else?) that resulted in a login prompt.

Comment: Just reinstall and give a password and username when asked by the installer!

Answer (score 2):

There is no "trial" login or password. The login is the name entered when installing Ubuntu and the password is also set when installing the operating system the first time.

If you haven't installed Ubuntu yet and are running it from a flash drive or DVD, there is no need for a password since the system just boots up then.